# How to find Integral $\int_{0}^{1/2} (e^x - 1)/x \,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

can you give me any advice how to caluclate $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} \,dx$ ? I need to use series. I tried to split it as
$$
\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{e^x}{x} \,dx - \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{x} \,dx$$ and then I can use a series for the first equation but I get another $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{x} \,dx$. Can I somehow evaluate these integrals or I need to use a completely different approach. Thanks!

Comment: [In terms of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28e%5Ex-1%29%2Fx+from+0+to+1%2F2) the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions) & [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), it's $\operatorname{Ei}(\tfrac12)-\gamma+\ln2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot split the integral into two unless at least one of them is convergent.

By the series definition of the exponential function, for $x\ne 0$
$$
\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\frac1x(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots )
=1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots 
$$
Now define the function $f:[0,1/2]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ if $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=1$. Then the function $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

So you can write
$$
f(x)=1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \frac{e^x-1}{x}\,dx=\int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx=
\int_0^{1/2}(1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots)\,dx
$$

Now do [integration term by term](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eagk22/uniform.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LyubomirRuzhinski you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle x\ne0\implies\frac{e^x-1}x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this! I was now trying to solve it and I saw that the integrals with 1/x can be canelled (silly mistake from me), can you tell me if I can cancel them even though they cant be solved?

Comment: I would like to help you, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: So first I split it as $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{e^x}{x} \,dx$ - $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{x} \,dx$ . Then I represent $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{e^x}{x} \,dx$ as $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^k / k! }{x} \,dx$ =>  $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^k / k! }{x} \,dx$  => $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{x} \,dx + \int_{0}^{1/2}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^(k-1) / k!}\,dx$ . Now if we replace this in the first equation they  the 1/x integrals get cancelled and I need to calcuate only the integral of the sum. Is this approach right?

Comment: No, it is not, since both integrals $\int_0^{1/2}\frac{e^x}x\,\mathrm dx$ and $\int_0^{1/2}\frac1x\,\mathrm dx$ diverge.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1/2}{\expo{x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x} \,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ -x}{=}\,\,\,
-\int_{-1/2}^{0}{\expo{-x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &
\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}
\bracks{-\int_{-1/2}^{\Lambda}{\expo{-x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x
+ \int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\expo{-x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}
\left[-{\rm P.V.}\int_{-1/2}^{\Lambda}
{\expo{-x} \over x}\,\dd x\right.
\\[2mm] &\ \phantom{\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}\,\,\,}
+ \int_{-1/2}^{\Lambda}{\dd x \over x} + 
\ln\pars{\Lambda}\pars{\expo{-\Lambda} - 1}
\\[2mm] &\
\left.\phantom{\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}\,\,\,}+ \int_{0}^{\Lambda}\ln\pars{x}\expo{-x}\dd x\right]
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\on{E_{i}}\pars{1 \over 2} + \ln\pars{2} - \gamma}
\approx 0.5702 \\ &
\end{align}

- $\ds{\on{E_{i}}}$: *Exponential Integral Function*.
  $\ds{\on{E_{i}}\pars{z} \equiv -{\rm P.V.}\int_{-z}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} \over x}\dd x}$.
- $\ds{\gamma}$: *Euler-Mascheroni Constant* which is equal to $\ds{\phantom{\gamma:}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\expo{-x}\dd x}$.